# Using .NET MVC 4.0 VirtualPathProviders in a web farm scenario

Tags: caching, distributed, mv, virtualpathprovider, cache-dependency

We have an application that relies heavily on a virtual file system that extends the .NET System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider architecture.
We use chaining to search through...
(A)contentresourceprovider (extends virtualpathprovider)
(B)assemblyresourceprovider (ditto)
(C)physical file system

The vpp's are registered on app initialisation like so...

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new AssemblyResourceProvider());
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new ContentResourceProvider());
```

This problem is relative to the ContentResourceProvider (see below)

```
public class ContentResourceProvider : System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider
{
    #region Methods 

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        var result = ContentResourceProvider.IsContentResourcePath(virtualPath) ?     ((ContentResourceVirtualFile)this.GetFile(virtualPath)).Exists : Previous.FileExists(virtualPath);
        return result;
    }

    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        var result = ContentResourceProvider.IsContentResourcePath(virtualPath) ? new ContentResourceCacheDependency(virtualPath) : Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
        return result;
    }

    public override System.Web.Hosting.VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        var result = ContentResourceProvider.IsContentResourcePath(virtualPath) ? new ContentResourceVirtualFile(virtualPath) : Previous.GetFile(virtualPath);
        return result;
    }

    public override string GetFileHash(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies)
    {
        var result = base.GetFileHash(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies);
        return result;
    }

    public static bool IsContentResourcePath(string virtualPath)
    {
        var pattern = @"~?/\(ContentManagementResource\)";
        var result = Regex.IsMatch(virtualPath, pattern, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return result;
    }

    #endregion Methods 
}
```

Basically this all works great and whenever we update content via our cms tools the virtual files and removed from cache and reopened/compiled into razor views.
All good so far....
However we recently deployed this to a server farm and it seems the whole innate System.Web.Hosting virtual file provider thingy does not scale (obviously) it's relative to the particular server that stores the virtual files in memory etc.
This means that if User A makes a change to a razor view via cms tools and the operation is carried out on Server A, user B making another change on Server B will then provide undesirable results despite the fact the content is coming from the same Database. This is because the virtual files systems caching the razor views are unique to the web server they are running on, likewise the cachedepedencies are only triggered on the relative server.

I've tried using the distributed cache packages like AppFabric, Memcached, NCache. These aren't adequate because they depend on you manually writng code that inserts Serialized objects into the distributed cache. Firstly the .NET vpp memory stuff is effectively managed under the hood with strict design patterns enforced, also the CacheDependency class isn't serializable.

Having done many hours of research I cannot find a solution online.

Surely the whole .NET MVC 4.0 VirtualPathProvider/CacheDependency systems architecture must have a way of scaling across more then one server?

I guess from my understanding of this matter I'm asking is there a way to scale the System.Web.Hosting cache memory across more than one server so that virtual content and Cache Dependencies attached to these files work as intended?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.